# I am trying to integrate Qualtrics survey with Unity3D game engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, qualtrics, surveymonkey

I am using the Unity3D game engine with C# and I have created a game which collects a few files and survey responses from the game player. Is it possible to create a survey on Qualtrics and then submit the response (survey answers and txt files) via. an API call from my game?

PS:- Is there a support to submit survey answers and text files using some API calls?

The in-game survey looks like the one below and there is a text file generated by the game during the game play. I'd need to send the survey responses and text files to Qualtrics.
[image]

Comment: You can import responses into a Qualtrics survey: https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/import-responses

Comment: it says that I can use txt files to import, but they no where mentioned what should be the format of file :/

https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/import-survey-1

Comment: You're look at the wrong api call.  Look at the one I posted in my comment. The format is csv.