# Import file responses into Qualtrics using API

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, qualtrics

My Qualtrics survey consists of the Likert type and file response questions, a survey can be previewed [here](https://asu.co1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_2mKNlTvN3IlePOt). Preview screenshot also attached below. This is linked to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712289/i-am-trying-to-integrate-qualtrics-survey-with-unity3d-game-engine) which I posted on this topic, where I am trying to submit survey response from a Unity Game. I can submit the response to Likert type questions by creating a CSV file and then calling the API, but how do I submit the txt/csv file as a response to the second question for the same response(Engagement data dump through API call). Another workaround I thought was to use a text-box as the second question where I can dump the entire data, but the problem is that Qualtrics text-box allows responses smaller than 20k characters only.

If Qualtrics doesn't support this, is there any other way to google sheet API or Google API script that lets you do that?

[image]

Comment: The Drive API allows you to perform file uploads and get links to those files. Without you showing how you are calling functions we can't really help you further.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @tehhowch I was able to upload the files to google drive, but unfortunately it seems that the files will be uploaded to the google drive of the person playing the game. There will be about 200 people who will play the game anonymously and I need the game data for all of them to be uploaded to my google drive, otherwise I will have to ask them to email the txt files to me. Is there any way to accomplish this task?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49827814/bypass-drive-api-recurrent-permission-causing-the-unity-pc-build-game-to-freeze